# cannot start 'node.exe': Not found in PATH

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

When I try this command in my vs-code terminal,

$ node -v

I get this error :

winpty: error: cannot start 'node.exe': Not found in PATH

However, running the same command in the regular Command Prompt works without any issues.

This problem is preventing me from using Node.js in VSCode effectively. How can I resolve this issue and make Node.js work in the VSCode terminal?

I am using Git Bash in VS code

Output of echoing the PATH:

````
path/to/npm:/c/Users/SANTHA/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/SANTHA/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files (x86)/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Users/SANTHA/anaconda3:/c/Users/SANTHA/anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/c/Users/SANTHA/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin:/c/Users/SANTHA/anaconda3/Library/bin:/c/Users/SANTHA/anaconda3/Scripts:/c/Users/SANTHA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:/c/Users/SANTHA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/c/Users/SANTHA/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/d/AVINASH/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/SANTHA/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/SANTHA/OneDrive/Desktop/avi/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin```

Output of where node(in command prompt): C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
````

Comment: what shell are you using in VS Code? Git Bash (I assume so if winpty is involved)? show the output of echoing the `PATH`, and show the output of `where node` / `whereis node`.

Comment: I have edited the outputs to the question itself. Kindly look into it..

Comment: I want to see the path and `where` output in both environments.

Comment: go read about how `PATH` works. what you wrote in the comments to the chatgpt answer you got concerns me. you put _directories_ in the `PATH`- the path to the directory _containing_ things you want for lookup- not the things you want for lookup themselves.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you're encountering suggests that the 'node.exe' executable is not found in the PATH environment variable when you the 'node -v' command in your VS code terminal. This issue can occur if the PATH in your vs code terminal environment differs from the PATH in your regular command prompt.

To solve this

1. Open VS Code
2. In the top menu, go to "File->Preferences->Settings"
3. In the search bar type "terminal.integrated.env.windows"
4. Click Edit in settings.json"
5. Add the following line in the file with the path of your node js

   "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PATH": "C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%PATH%"
   }

To get the location of your node installation type the following command in the command prompt of windows

```
where node
```

After adding the path restart vs code and try again

Comment: I don't find the problem solved on doing this....

"terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" }
This is the line I am adding to my settings.json file and correct me if I am wrong anywhere...
I would also mention that using '/' shows me error!!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541

Comment: "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"

I think the problem is that you are write "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" this part twice just write 

 "terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" }